# Searching for dependency of TimeDoctor2 at Ubuntu 22

Tags: ubuntu, dependencies

I am using the time doctor 2 application for a long time. I am using it to track my and my team's working time. Because they are working for me remotely.

2 days ago I update my ubuntu from 20 to 22, then that application stop working. The view is completely blank of that application. I contacted them and did not find any proper instruction to solve the issue. If anybody has already solved this issue by finding any dependency installation on Ubuntu 22 then it will be a great help for me.

Comment: You probably have to ask their support about instructions to install their commercial closed-source software. You pay good money for their software, so they should be able to provide support for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The support team didn't have a solution for me. However, I found a workaround that helped [here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1411940)

Run the following command in terminal

```
export QTWEBENGINE_DISABLE_SANDBOX=1
```

Then run:

```
~/timedoctor2/timedoctor2
```

**Note**: I needed to run again after closing the terminal.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem a week ago. Also contacted the support team and they took a remote session but could not troubleshoot this issue. Then they suggested downgrading my OS. I reinstalled Ubuntu 21.10 and now it is working perfectly again. They also said that they will pass this message to the product team. Let's see when they will update the application which will run on Ubuntu 22.04.

So, I think that there is no other way except to downgrade the OS.

Comment: They already replied to me, that they are working on it. Also, send me an email with some suggestions, but not worked for me. I am still waiting for the solution.